# Output individual array results, not using ngFor

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

How do you get one result from an observable.. I can easily use ngFor to loop over lots of results but if i want to output one result in a certain part of the page then another result how can i achieve this

the main function in my service class is the following which gets the data

```
    public getData() {
        this._http.get( this.apiStatic ).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
            this._dataStoreHomepageReasons.homepage_reasons = data.homepage_reasons;
            this._HomepageReasonsObserver.next(this._dataStoreHomepageReasons.homepage_reasons);
        }, error => console.log('Could not load projects.'),
        () => 'done');
    }
```

which returns this json

```
        {
            "homepage_reasons": [{
                "id": 1,
                "color": "",
                "heading": "section one",
                "paragraph": "<p>\n quote goes here\n      <\/p>",
                "image": "http:\/\/www.site.com\/\/2016-06\/9emjhxh4ch3nlbrkpph90v3spzkc1msw9dhm7op9.png"
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "color": "",
                "heading": "section one",
                "paragraph": "<p>\n quote goes here\n      <\/p>",
                "image": "http:\/\/www.site.com\/\/2016-06\/9emjhxh4ch3nlbrkpph90v3spzkc1msw9dhm7op9.png"
            }, {
                "id": 3,
                "color": "",
                "heading": "section one",
                "paragraph": "<p>\n quote goes here\n      <\/p>",
                "image": "http:\/\/www.site.com\/\/2016-06\/9emjhxh4ch3nlbrkpph90v3spzkc1msw9dhm7op9.png"
            }]
        }
```

I can access the data using this no problem

```
  <div class="inner" *ngFor="let h of homepage_reasons | async">>
    <blockquote>
      <p>{{h.image}}</p>
      <footer>
        <cite>
          <div class="subheading">{{h.heading}}</div><small>iQuate</small>
        </cite>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
```

However this outputs the results one after the other in a row.. I want to be able to put lets say homepage_reasons[0].image to output the first image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe from your component instead of from the service.

**Service**

```
private getData(): Observable<SomeDataType[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.api_url).map(response => response.json());
}
```

**Component**

```
export class SomeClassComponent {
    things: SomeDataType[];

.subscribe(
    things => this.things = things,
    error => console.log('Could not load projects.'),
    () => 'done');
```

Now you can get rid of the async pipe in your template, and you can use:

```
<img src="things[1]">
<img src="things[2]">
```

Or whatever it is you are trying to do. Does that help?

Comment: Perhaps I missed something but I tried to implement this and it didnt output anything :/

Comment: Ended up using this info but found that this tutorial outlinned the above method in more detail http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-2-http-observables

Answer (score 0):

Put an *ngIf, that way it waits to make sure that homepage_reasons is defined before trying to find the 0th element

```
<p *ngIf="homepage_reasons">{{homepage_reasons[0].image}}<p>
```

Comment: That only works if you are waiting on a result and dont want to display a null value.. Im trying to figure out how to access an individial record in an array rather than using an ngFor loop over everything

Comment: You are right... I tried `{{homepage_reasons[0]?.image}}` with some of my own data and async calls and the edited answer works for me

Comment: Just tried it there and I still get errors.. platform-browser.umd.js:962 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

You can use `ngTemplateOutlet`

**Create the template**

- Create a template element somewhere in your components template that contains the structure how you want to render an item.

  The template also can be passed from the outside and acquired using

```
constructor(private tmpl:TemplateRef) {}
```

or

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) tmpl:TemplateRef;
```

- We add a template variable for simple sibling reference `#hpReasons`
- The variables that should be available need to be declared. `let-image` declares a local variable `image` that holds the value of `image` from the value passed to `ngOutletContext`

```
  <template #hpReasons let-image="image" let-heading="heading">
    <div class="inner">>
      <blockquote>
        <p>{{image}}</p>
        <footer>
          <cite>
            <div class="subheading">{{heading}}</div><small>iQuate</small>
          </cite>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </template>
```

**Use the template**

To actually render an item use `ngTemplateOutlet` to refer to a `TemplateRef` and `ngOutletContext` to pass a data item

```
<template [ngOutletContext]="hpReasons" [ngOutletContext]="(homepage_reasons | async)[2]"></template>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview)